# JqGrid Column Sorting on EMAIL

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I am trying to sort the email column using JqGrid, but it is behaving inconsistently.

For example, if my grid is below

```
Name        Phone        Email
-------------------------------
Name A      123456       ABCDEFG
Name B      654321       abc2@yahoo.com
Name C      987456       PETER.WI
```

If i am trying to sort the above grid by using Email column it is not giving expected output, instead it is giving output like below if I am trying sort in ascending order.

```
Name        Phone        Email
-------------------------------

Name C      987456       ABCDEFG
Name B      654321       PETER.WI
Name A      123456       abc2@yahoo.com
```

My guess is JqGrid not working for column which is containing @ symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to set the `sorttype` of the column:

```
sorttype: "string"
```

(or at least make sure you don't put there int/float).

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vvz2a3cy/

Comment: I have updated my input and output in my question and tried same in JSFIDDEL, i am not getting the expected output. Can you please help me on this @Dekel

Comment: Thank for your help. I have included "ignoreCase:true" now it is working fine